# Can Java's Stream.collect() return null?

Tags: java, java-stream

The JavaDoc for Stream.collect() says that it returns "the result of the reduction".  That doesn't tell me if code like this can return null for `filteredList`:

```
List<String> filteredList = inputList.stream()
    .filter(c -> c.isActive())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I would expect that if it could return null then it would return an `Optional`, but it doesn't say that either.

Is it documented anywhere whether `Stream.collect()` can return null?

Comment: No this will return you an empty list even if nothing gets filtered

Comment: I tested all Collectors returned by `java.util.stream.Collectors.toXXX` and they will all return an empty collection (not `null`) if provided an empty stream.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`Collector.toList()` will return an **empty** List for you.

Here is the implementation:

```
public static <T>
Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList() {
    return new CollectorImpl<>((Supplier<List<T>>) ArrayList::new, List::add,
                               (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },
                               CH_ID);
}
```

As you can see `ArrayList::new` is being used as a container for your items.

From JavaDoc of [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html):

> A mutable reduction operation that
>   **accumulates input elements into a mutable result container**, optionally
>   transforming the accumulated result into a final representation after
>   all input elements have been processed. Reduction operations can be
>   performed either sequentially or in parallel.
>
> A Collector is specified by four functions that work together to
>   accumulate entries into a mutable result container, and optionally
>   perform a final transform on the result. They are:
>
> - **creation of a new result container (supplier())**
> - incorporating a new data element into a result container (accumulator())
> - combining two result containers into one (combiner())
> - performing an optional final transform on the container (finisher())

And

> A sequential implementation of a reduction using a collector would
>   **create a single result container using the supplier function**, and
>   invoke the accumulator function once for each input element. A
>   parallel implementation would partition the input, **create a result**
>   **container for each partition**, accumulate the contents of each
>   partition into a subresult for that partition, and then use the
>   combiner function to merge the subresults into a combined result.

So as long as you don't do weird things like combine function return `null`, the `Collector` always return at least a `mutable container` using your provided `supplier` function.

And I think it's very counter-intuitive if an implementation would ever return `null` container.

Answer (score 28):

This is not dependent on `Stream.collect`, but on the individual [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html). `Collectors.toList()` will return an empty `ArrayList`.

That said, there's no reason someone couldn't use a weird `Collector` to return null in certain circumstances:

```
.collect(
    Collector.of(
        ArrayList::new,
        ArrayList::add,
        (a, b) -> {
            a.addAll(b);
            return a;
        },
        a -> a.isEmpty() ? null : a  // finisher replaces empty list with null
    )
);
```

So the `Collector` is the thing you need to remember to check. I believe all of the [`Collectors` available out-of-the-box](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) will return empty collections, as you'd expect.

Comment: I believe this *is* the correct answer, on the phone now, but is there really no specification about this? I would doubt it...

Comment: agree with Eugene, this should be the correct answer

Answer (score 13):

You could use `Collectors::collectingAndThen` to pass collect() result to a `Function<T,R>`. Return value of the `Function<T,R>` will be return value of collect().

```java
List<String> filteredList = inputList.stream()
 .filter(c -> c.isActive())
 .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), c -> !c.isEmpty()?c:null));
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this part of the documentation says that it cannot be null:

> Returns a Collector that accumulates the input elements into a **ne**w
>   **List**.

**Highlights** added by me. I think this **new List** means that something that isn't null.

I started to check `ReferencePipeline.collect()` to check whether it's true for the actual implementation. Unfortunately, it was a futile attempt. There are so many cases here, like is it parallel? is it after a `forEach`? etc.

Comment: very thin IMO... If that is indeed what the documentation means, than there is a problem with it not being explicit enough

Comment: In my opinion, javadoc should be presize and to the point. It clearly says what you can expect from the method which is a "new List". It should not mention other values which this method "does not" return.

Answer (score 1):

This is collector-dependant. The one You're using (Collectors.toList()) returns an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following code is a good implementation if you really need to return null when the list is empty (assuming the type of the variable `c` is `MyObj`):

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.collectingAndThen;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

...

  List<String> filteredList = inputList.stream()
    .filter(MyObj::isActive)
    .collect(collectingAndThen(toList(), Stream::of)
    .filter(List::isEmpty)
    .findAny()
    .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

No collect will never return null, in order to check use `isEmpty()` instead of null